# No attribute 'set_values' or 'At_indexer' error due to set_values and at() in pandas due to Python3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, series

I am new to pandas and still learning.
I am trying to add two numbers in series label-wise. One method is this:

```
    numbers = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0,1000,10000))
    for label, value in numbers.iteritems():
        numbers.set_values(label, value+2)
    numbers.head()
```

Output:

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'set_values'

Now upon research I found out that it was deprecated and at() is used instead.
so when I used it like this:

```
for label, value in numbers.iteritems():
    numbers.at(label, value+2)
numbers.head()
```

Output:

> TypeError: '_AtIndexer' object is not callable

So when I use it like this with at[]:

```
for label, value in numbers.iteritems():
    numbers.at[label, value+2]
numbers.head()
```

I get this output:

```
   KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-b1f985a669d7> in <module>
      1 for label, value in numbers.iteritems():
----> 2     numbers.at[label, value+2]
      3 
      4 numbers.head()

C:\Users\Public\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2078             return self.obj.loc[key]
   2079 
-> 2080         return super().__getitem__(key)
   2081 
   2082     def __setitem__(self, key, value):

C:\Users\Public\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2025 
   2026         key = self._convert_key(key)
-> 2027         return self.obj._get_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)
   2028 
   2029     def __setitem__(self, key, value):

C:\Users\Public\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _get_value(self, label, takeable)
    987 
    988         # Similar to Index.get_value, but we do not fall back to positional
--> 989         loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
    990         return self.index._get_values_for_loc(self, loc, label)
    991 

C:\Users\Public\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    356                 except ValueError as err:
    357                     raise KeyError(key) from err
--> 358             raise KeyError(key)
    359         return super().get_loc(key, method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
    360 

KeyError: (0, 10002)
```

What am I doing wrong and what can be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`at` is used as an accessor to the index given by its argument. When you pass `label, value+2` to it, it sees this argument as a 2-tuple and looks for an index named literally `(0, 10002)` in the first turn but it fails since your series has integer indices `0, 1, ...`, not tuples.

So you can leave `label` only in `at` and set what it returns to `value + 2`:

```
numbers = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0,1000,10000))

for label, value in numbers.iteritems():
    # lookup the value and set it
    numbers.at[label] = value + 2
```

(noting that this is equivalent to `numbers += 2`).

Comment: @Abraham Are you sure you're using the for-loop variable `value` when doing `numbers.at[label] = value + 2`? Or are you using some other variable in place of `value` there?

Comment: Thank you it worked. I was trying to manipulate numbers += 2 in for loop, to see how long it works by using the timeit function and it worked.

Comment: I am sry, i think when i was expremient with the value and statement , my numbers got mixed up. It worked and Its clear now. Thank you. Yes sure I will accept it.